# Where is the x86 release of ros2 foxy?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the install [page](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Binary/)
it says: "We support Ubuntu Linux Focal Fossa (20.04) 64-bit x86 and 64-bit ARM."

But in the downloads [page](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/releases) I can only see releases for amd and arm.

Has it not been released yet? Do I need to build from source? Or should I just download the amd version?

I have a hp laptop with a 64bit Intel I5 pro, running Ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354748/where-is-the-x86-release-of-ros2-foxy?/) by [CraigH92](https://answers.ros.org/users/54432/craigh92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2020-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMD64 is a reference to the architecture used by Intel and AMD, you're good to go. :)

---

Originally posted by [kneave](https://answers.ros.org/users/55611/kneave/) with karma: 96 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-12**:
Article on Wikipedia about this: [wikipedia/X86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64).

@CraigH92: AMD was "the first" with a publicly available and popular 64bit extension to plain x86, and MS chose to follow their naming convention. So that's why we all call it `amd64`. It's the name of the *instruction set*, it does not refer to AMD as in: only AMD processors.

Intel's processors also support the `amd64` (or `x86-64`) instruction set.